# how to perform this join in laravel

Tags: php, sql, join, laravel-5

I have a table in my database called **JobCardOps** and a model JobCardOp.php. Fields of this table include *OpNum*, *JobCardNum*, *PrevOpNum*, *OpStatus*. An row is uniquely identified by the JobCardNum and OpNum pair. Now, I considered having another field called PreviousOpStatus which contains the status of the previous Op, by then I wondered whether I could do this with Join.

So to clarify, When I retrieve a group of JobCardOp models from the database I want to add another field on the end; 'PreviousOpStatus'.
I know ill need something like;

```
 $Ops = JobCardOp::where('JobCardNum', '=', $someJobNum)
  ->join('JobCardOps as JobCardOps_1, some constraint)
  ->select('JobCardOps.*', 'JobCardOps_1.OpStatus as PreviousOpStatus')
  ->get();
```

Where JobCardOps_1 is somehow offset by 1 if that makes sense. Can anyone help if this can be done?

Thanks